# Unit circle is divided into $n$ equal pieces, what is the least value of the perimeters of the $n$ parts?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

A unit disk is divided into $n$ equal pieces, that is, each piece has **area** $\dfrac\pi n$.

equal "pieces" means equal  **area**

Let  $l_1, l_2,\dotsc,l_n$ be the perimeters of the $n$ parts, respectively.

What is the least value of $l_1+l_2+\dotsb+l_n$?

That is, how to calculate $L_n=\min\{l_1+l_2+\dotsb+l_n\}$ ?

---

For $n=8$, as far as I know, $L_8\lt 2\pi+16$

Any help will be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't $L_8 = 2\pi + 16$

Comment: @VarunIyer: Nope. A checker board like pattern has a lower perimeter. I have just verified this for $n=12$.

Comment: @IlikeSerena I am confused. Please look at my answer. Isn't this what the OP was asking?

Comment: What do you mean by "equal pieces"? Equal area? Equal perimeter? Or are all the pieces congruent?

Comment: @VarunIyer: A partition in pies will guarantee a perimeter of $2\pi+2n$, which I believe is what you are aiming at. But there are alternative partitions with lower perimeter. Note that a shape like a square has a lower perimeter than a sharp pointed pie. I have to admit that I am assuming the pieces have equal area but not necessarily equal shape.

Comment: @DarthGeek equal area. Thanks!

Comment: There is a little issue since the pieces can all be measurable but without having a "perimeter", since their boundaries may be not a rectifiable set.

Comment: I am a bit confused too. In the drawing, there are 2 circles. Which one is that unit circle? What is the use (and the dimensions if needed) of the other circle?

Comment: Is your diagram really optimal? An optimal solution would have only straight lines separating the pieces, surely?

Comment: @TonyK: you're right, if a piece is not convex we can adjust things and lower the total perimeter without affecting areas. Anyway, a "small degree of concavity" does not seem to affect the asymptotics really much.

Comment: @TonyK The picture show $L_8\lt 2\pi+16$,  which is not optimal

Answer (score 9):

The isoperimetric inequality gives the lower bound: 
$$L_n\geq 2\pi\sqrt{n},$$ 
and I believe we can achieve:
$$L_n\leq C\cdot\sqrt{n}$$
through the following strategy: choose some integers $m_1,\ldots,m_k$ such that:
$$0\leq m_1\leq m_2\leq\ldots\leq m_k,\qquad m_1+\ldots+m_k = n$$
and consider concentric regular polygons $\Gamma_1,\ldots,\Gamma_k$, with center in the center of the circle, such that $\Gamma_i$ has $m_i$ vertices and area $\frac{m_1+\ldots+m_i}{n}\pi$, then split the "polygonal annulus" between $\Gamma_i$ and $\Gamma_{i+1}$, where $\Gamma_{n+1}$ is the original circle, into $m_i$ equal parts with a set of $m_i$ segments having minimum perimeter. If the sequence $m_1,\ldots,m_k$ is properly chosen (close to be an arithmetic sequence, in order that all the pieces are "almost equal" one each other), we stay quite close to the lower bound for $L_n$. I still do not have a rigorous proof ot his, but the conjecture 
$$L_n = \Theta(\sqrt{n})$$
is very likely to hold in my opinion.
Just to make my argument visually clear, here there is a likely almost-minimal split with $n=10$, with $m_1=0,m_2=3,m_3=7$:
[image]

In order to get the "reversed isoperimetric inequality" we just need to show that we can take all the pieces "close enough to be a circle". It is quite trivial that we can have all the pieces with at most six sides (including the curvilinear one for the pieces on the boundary of the circle) and convex, we just need to prove that for any piece, there exists a circumscribed rectangle whose side ratio (as the ratio between the diameter and the "orthogonal width")
is less a certain constant $K$, in order to prove that
$$L_n\leq 2\pi K'\sqrt{n}.$$
The problem now boils down to two components: the arithmetic one, that is the choice of the best sequence $\{m_i\}$, and the geometric one, i.e. the hunt for the $K$ and $K'$ constants.

**Lemma $1$**: The diameter of any piece belonging to the annulus $A_i$ between $\Gamma_i$ and $\Gamma_{i+1}$ is bounded by $\frac{1}{m_i}$ times the length of the circumcircle of $\Gamma_{i+1}$, hence by $$\frac{1}{m_i}\sqrt{\frac{m_1+\ldots+m_{i+1}}{n}\cdot\frac{2\pi}{n\sin\frac{2\pi}{m_i}}}.$$
Moreover, for any piece belonging  to $A_i$, the "orthogonal width" is bounded below by the difference of the circumradii of $\Gamma_i$ and $\Gamma_{i+1}$, hence $K$ depends only on the sequence $\{m_i\}.$

**Lemma $2$**: For any convex shape with area $A$ and "Kakutani ratio" $\leq K$, the perimeter is bounded by:
$$ 2\left(\sqrt{K}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{K}}\right)\sqrt{A}.$$

Assuming that for any $n$ we can achieve the realistic constant $K=3$ through Lemma 1, we have:

> $$ L_n \leq 3\pi\sqrt{n}.$$

This bound is worse than the trivial $2\pi+2n$-bound for any $n\leq 15$, but it is asymptotically optimal. The interesting thing is that $K$ may be big only for pieces that lie near to the center of the circle, so, essentially, only for $m_1$ pieces. This leads to a stronger conjecture:

$$ L_n \leq 2\pi\sqrt{n} + K''. $$

However, this very last line may incredibly difficult to prove, if not even wrong. If my algorithm leads to the optimal solution, the case $n=9$ (in which we have a trisected hexagon in the center, with $K\approx\sqrt{3}$) gives that $K''$ must be at least $2.7$.

Comment: Nice to use the isoperimetric inequality! Technically $L_n$ can't be exactly equal to $2\pi \sqrt{n}$ because that would mean all the pieces are themselves circles.

Comment: @DavidButlerUofA: you're obviously right, we just need to show that we can take all the pieces "close enough" to a circle to prove the reversed inequality. For sure, if the sequence $\{m_i\}$ is well-chosen, we can take every piece having at most six sides (including the curvilinear ones for the pieces on the boundary).

Comment: I think the $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$ estimate is almost certain to hold for exactly the reason you suggest; while the constant won't be best, I think you can prove the conjecture with a relatively explicit construction - just take a 'nearly-inscribed' triangle of area a rational multiple of pi with its vertices near the circumference, then chop the triangle into $k^2$ pieces for suitably-chosen $k$ and split the three 'wedges' surrounding it into $n-k^2$ pieces to fit.  This won't necessarily work for all $n$, but you should be able to get infinitely many $n$ this way.

Comment: (This construction depends on being able to split the wedges appropriately, but I believe that you can prove that a convex shape with diameter to 'minimum diameter' ratio less than 2 can be split transversely into two other convex shapes that also have diameter-to-minimum-diameter ratio less than 2.)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: I think we can improve the $3\pi\sqrt{n}$ bound by considering an hexagonal tiling (that is better than a triangular tiling since the hexagon has a greater ratio between the area and the square of the perimeter) then adjusting things near the boundary of the circle through Lemma 2. Are you willing to cooperate? I will be glad to offer a bounty for this.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio The advantage with the triangular tiling was that it chopped up so cleanly into manageable pieces, but I agree that you can do much better.  I don't have a ton of time to work on this, sadly (preparations for some awesome life events in the near future), but I have thoughts about an annulus sequence - definitely far-from-optimal - that would guarantee the $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$ bound, and I'll see if I can't get a specific constant out of it.  If so, I'll amend this answer with a quick description of it?

Answer (score 3):

**DISCLAIMER:** This is not an answer! It just provides visual and numerical aspects of the problem in an illustrative way.

I made dynamic diagrams producing configurations similar to the one the OP gave in the question. My method was simply to assume that each annulus would have a width of approximately $\sqrt{\pi/n}$ which is the side length of $n$ identical squares having the same area as the circle. Then I adjusted the width by simply rounding to match a whole number of segments of area $\pi/n$ into each annulus. The result can be seen here:

[image: Configuration of Circle Divisions][image]

It would be much harder to program a more fine tuned approach. I chose thise circular and in that quite regular construction due to its simplicity. Yet it seems pretty good already!

If anyone care to play around with it more, they can visit my interactive file that goes up to $n=700$ in this manner. Note how the actual perimeter of these configurations seem to follow a curve close to the lower bound of $2\pi\sqrt n$ given by [Jack D'Aurizio](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/44121/jack-daurizio) in his [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/880222/94971). Here is the interactive file to play with:

http://www.geogebratube.org/student/m138801

Answer (score 2):

For $n>2$, let $a=\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{3n\sqrt 3}} $, so that the area $ a^2\frac32\sqrt 3$ of a regular with side length $a$ is $\frac \pi n$. Overlay the unit circle with a corresponding hexagonal lattice. 
We may assume wlog. that no lattice point is on the circle.
Then there are $O(\sqrt n)$ hexagons intersecting the circle.
More precisely, these intersecting hexagons are within the annulus with inner radius $1-2a$ and outer radius $1+2a$, hence their combined area is $<\pi(1+2a)^2-\pi(1-2a)^2=8\pi a$ and their count $m$ is $$m<8na=\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt 3}}\cdot \sqrt n.$$
At most four of the edges of such a hexagon are fully inside the unit circle, hence the total length $p$ of these edges is
$$p\le 4am<32na^2 =\frac{64\pi}{3\sqrt 3}.$$
(Admittedly, the constant factor in tis estimate is very crude).
The $n'\ge n-m$ hexagons that are fully inside the unit circle contribute $6an'$ to the perimeter sum.
We partition the remaining area into $n-n'\le m$ parts with $(n-n')$ radial lines of lenth $<2a$, hence these $n-n'$ parts contribute at most $2\pi+p+2(n-n')\cdot 2a$ to the perimeter sum.
We conclude that 
$$\begin{align}L_n &\le 6an'+2\pi +p+4a(n-n')\\
&\le 6an -2a(n-n') +p+2\pi\\
&\le 6an +p+2\pi\\
&= 2\sqrt{{2\pi\sqrt 3}}\cdot \sqrt n+\frac{64\pi}{3\sqrt 3}+2\pi.\end{align}$$
Numerically, $$\begin{align}2\sqrt{2\pi\sqrt 3}&\approx 6.597817 \end{align}$$
and remarkably, this is just about $1.05$ times $2\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent work on the general case. Looking at some specific low n cases, it appears that the lowest n-value for which we can get less than the upper bound of 2pi + 2n is actually 5. This can be acheived through having a square, of side sqrt(pi/5), whose centre is the centre of the circle; and drawing lines from it to the perimeter of the circle. This yields an Ln of approximately 0.16 less than 2pi+10 (exact value is easily calculated).

A different thought: Can it be proven that the optimal solution will never contain a curved cut?